# Laravel Many To Many Relationship Tutorial

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, many-to-many

i refer tutorial laravel on youtube, then i encounter this error

this is FollowsController.php

```
    public function store(User $user)
    {
        return auth()->user()->following()->toggle($user->profile);
    }
```

it say the following is undefined method

this is user.php

```
    public function following()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class);
    }
```

this is profile.php

```
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

i try to solve it, but i cannot find why it happen like that.
Hope you can help me to finish this tutorial.

Comment: Could you please show us the full error?

Comment: There has to be a `toggle()` method somewhere right? Where is it? If you don't have it I guess you've found your problem. However, to properly help you we will need the full error message and all the code in the `Profile` and `User` models.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're signed in as anyone when trying to run that code

Comment: I suggest you watch this youtube video. to better understand laravel Relationships
https://youtu.be/9Hpt4phPqFA